# Azure packages disappearing after installing it via ssh

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I install supervisord and mysql via azure ssh.

But after a few days, all my installed packages are disappeared, and all my tables in mysql are also gone.

It seems that the server is updated regularly, but my files are fine.

Do i need to set somethings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a PaaS service, not a virtual machine and you can't install applications like MySQL on it. Well, Azure let you do it but as you experienced, when Azure does its maintenance, your app will/can be moved to another host. This is normal behavior.

One solution on App Service is to use containers and a Docker Compose file.